# Visual Studio 2012 disassembly error dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging, disassembly

This is a general error with Visual Studio 2012 that has come up recently. While debugging any C++ application and after hitting a break-point, clicking "Go To Disassembly" will produce the following error dialog:

> Disassembly cannot be displayed for the source location. Uncaught
>   exception thrown by method called through Reflection.

I've tried reinstalling and repairing VS2012 with no effect. Even the simplest console application will show the same error, so it's not specific to a project and has to be a problem with the system configuration. At this point I'm just clueless what module Visual Studio is failing to load - google hasn't provided any solutions either.

The only possible link could be my recent removal of older .NET Framework redistributable packages *(since I've got .NET 4.5 SDK and multi-target pack, I figured the older ones weren't necessary)*.

I really need the disassembly view working *(it worked quite well before)* and I was hoping someone has come across this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: After downloading Visual Studio 2012 **Update 2**, the problem solved itself. I guess it was a bug with the vanilla release.